# Countifs with a complex criteria

Tags: excel

Is there an option to place a complex condition of `count()/countif()`in Excel? By "complex" I mean something that includes `and`, `or`, other logical operations and their combinations. The simpler case would be `and` or `or` only. For example I'd like to count those cells with value less than 3 or value equals to `false`.

Comment: What do you mean by "complex condition"? `OR` is not that complex, as it allows for splitting into "simple" conditions (answer by nutsch). Perhaps `AND` is complex, and you have `COUNTIFS` for that (as you used in the title). Perhaps posting a sample of an input range, and the result you want to obtain, would help.

Comment: @sancho.s clarified the question - kindly see and provide a better answer if you have one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a `countif` (or `countifs`), an `OR` transaction can be computed by addition, e.g.

```
=COUNTIF(range,"<3")+COUNTIF(range,FALSE)
```

An `AND` transaction can not easily be handled in a `COUNTIF`, but can be managed with either a `COUNTIFS` or a `SUMPRODUCT`, e.g.

```
=COUNTIFS(range,"<3",range,">1")

=SUMPRODUCT((range<3)*(range>1)*1)
```

Comment: Widened the question scope a bit - could you add up to your answer please?

Comment: Thanks! BTW I'd really like to know the reason for the downvote.

Answer (score 2):

There are cases where using addition of `COUNTIF` does not give a result corresponding to `OR`.
E.g., to count the number of cells in `range2` containing the substrings "a" or "b"

```
=COUNTIF(range2,"*a*")+COUNTIF(range2,"*b*")
```

will double count a cell containing "ab". The correct formula is then

```
=COUNTIF(range2,"*a*")+COUNTIF(range2,"*b*")-COUNTIFS(range2,"*a*",range2,"*b*")
```

(i.e., counting numbers of elements in sets, N(AuB)=N(A)+N(B)-N(AnB)).
The problem appears when both conditions tested can be true at the same time (not the case of the example by the OP, where N(AnB)=0).